# Alter column name of a GBQ table whose source is a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a GBQ table which is created from a google sheet. The names of the columns have been updated in the google sheet but it is not reflecting in the table. So i tried using ALTER command and gave the error that it is an external table and cannot be altered.
IS there any workaround or I have to recreate the table using the google sheet to reflect the updated column names?

Comment: Hi @schywalker,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it helps, otherwise let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-tables#limitations):

> You cannot modify external data tables using DML or other methods. External tables are read-only for BigQuery.

As a workaround  you can consider the following example:

- **Step1**: Create a new table with new column name.
  Ex: *create table `my-project.my-dataset.my-new-table`(stackid int64,caseno int64)*
- **Step2**: Copy data from the old table to the new table using the INSERT statement.

  Ex: *insert into `my-project.my-dataset.my-new-table`  (select * from  `my-project.my-dataset.my-old-table`);*

**RESULT :**
[image]

In my opinion instead of creating a new table, you can consider creating a view also. This would enable you to avoid repeat execution of insert statements for new data. Before diving into views, please take a look at these links: [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro#view_limitations), [link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro#:%7E:text=BigQuery%27s%20views%20are%20logical%20views,by%20the%20top%2Dlevel%20query.), and [link3](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro).